# how to give values to database

Tags: java, android, database

i was practising to create,store and get data's from database, i am successful in giving data's inside the coding's itself. but when i create an edit box and try to store data its not working. the following is my code can any one pls help me to solve the problem

pls teach me from my code

```
{ 

   setContentView(R.layout.add);
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB= null;
    String MY_DATABASE_NAME = "add.db";
    String TableName = "names";
    String Data = "";           


    d1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget40);      
    d2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget42);      
    d3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget43);      
    d4 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget45);
    d5 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget46);


    MyDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
         MyDB.setVersion(1);
         MyDB.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
         MyDB.setLockingEnabled(true);
         //create a database
         MyDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
                 + TableName
                 + "(firstname VARCHAR, middlename VARCHAR, lastname VARCHAR, dob INT(8), dor INT(8));" );
        // add data sets to the table
        MyDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TableName+ " (firstname, middlename, lastname, dob, dor)"+ " VALUES (' ', ' ' , ' ', , );");

        Cursor c = MyDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);

         int A = c.getColumnIndex("firstname");
         int B = c.getColumnIndex("middlename"); 
         int C = c.getColumnIndex("lastname");
         int D = c.getColumnIndex("dob");
         int E = c.getColumnIndex("dor");


      // Check if our result was valid.
       c.moveToFirst();
       if (c != null) {
        // Loop through all Results
        do {
         String q = c.getString(A);
         String w = c.getString(B);
         String e = c.getString(C);
         int r = c.getInt(D);
         int t = c.getInt(E);

         Data =Data +q+" "+w+" "+e+" "+r+" "+t+"\n";

        }while(c.moveToNext());
       }
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText(Data);
       setContentView(tv);
    } 
}
```

i well know that it will crash. pls help me

Comment: Are you kidding me? I just wrote a pretty elaborate answer to your question and you go and start a new one on exactly the same topic? Jesus...

Comment: i am not kidding...i dont understand...i am very new to development... i dont have any colleagues in my work place to have a discussion...Sorry

Comment: if you are saying that "it will crash", it is better to show a stack trace of a crash to identify the right place and reason of a crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Zip file from [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) link and check there is Database creation,Edit and Delete..